# Redirect rule to an IP

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, azure-web-app-service, arr

I have a site hosted in azure.
I want to debug a certain scenario which happens there (in test env) and so I want all requests that come to that URL i.e. https://test.com to be redirected to my local IP ( after I port forward and handled everything on my own computer.
I have added a rule which almost works and this is what it looks like:

```
<rule name="Reverse" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />          
            <action type="Redirect" url="52.52.52.52/api/..." redirectType="Found"/>             
</rule>
```

What happens is that when the request comes to the server, it prepend the current host URL to the IP and it looks like this:

**test.com/52.52.52.52**

How do can I configure to not add the host name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I worked with the rewrite rules so this answer might not be definitive. But the "Found" 'redirectType' is going to result in a 302 response to the client (browser) and will include a "Location:" header with a full URL. Since you have not provided the host in your URL, it will use the host name that was in the request.

You need to put the protocol in the action "url=" like 'url="https://52.52.52.52/api/...'.

If you need this to work for both HTTP and HTTPS, you can either parse our the protocol from the {REQUEST_URI} or create a rewrite map and use the {HTTPS} server variable. [Details are here.](https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/url-rewrite-protocol-http-https-in-the-action)

Comment: Well, it partially works. If I set the redirect URL schema as http, it works but if I set it as https, it doesn't.

Comment: What does it do? You will have a problem with security if you don't have an SSL/TLS certificate for your IP address but that isn't related to the redirect.

Comment: It just gives me a 404. I have 2 bindings on the server which the request is directed to and I have a certificate.

Comment: I suggest you use something like Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to sniff the request/response to see what the "location:" header is in the response from the server. If you can't do that, post your rewrite rules config and I will see if I can try it.

Comment: already using fiddler.
Well, I put the https aside and just used http. It does reach my computer now but I get: 
404 unknown type extension ".aspx". The url is 
IP/pages/page.aspx

when I use localhost/pages/page.aspx it does work
Does the IP matter when it reaches IIS? I have .aspx in the MIME types

Comment: strange - I'm seeing lighttpd in the server header - it looks like it never reaches my local IIS

Comment: Can you post the response envelope? Is the IIS site running on port 80? If not, is the port number provided in the URL? Are you running lighttpd on your server?